# How can I enable an Apache module on ddev?

Tags: ddev

I'm using `webserver-type: apache-fpm` with ddev and need to enable a module. How do I do that?

Comment: This is useful for modules like mod_expires, mod_headers, etc. Some of those might get included in DDEV at some point, but you can always add more modules using this idea.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the best way to do this is with a .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile based on this one (if you needed hearteat module):

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM $BASE_IMAGE
RUN a2enmod heartbeat
```

That will enable a module long before apache actually comes up, so if you have an apache config that depends on the module, it will work OK.

An alternate technique is to use `a2enmod` inside the web container and then `apachectl graceful` to restart apache to pick up the changes.

So `ddev ssh` and then `a2enmod heartbeat && apache2ctl graceful` (if you were enabling the "heartbeat" module)

Using ddev exec: `ddev exec "a2enmod heartbeat && apache2ctl graceful"`

Using a post-start hook:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
  - exec: a2enmod heartbeat && apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: this looks promising but I run into an error before it can enable the module, is there an earlier hook we can use?  Workaround is to comment the config line that fails, ddev start, then uncomment and ddev start

Comment: I edited this to add the .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile technique, so the module is enabled long before the webserver sees your configuration. @joelpittet